# Texture memory-tex2D basics

Tags: cuda, texture2d

While using texture memory I have come across the following code:-

```
uint f = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
uint c = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

uint read = tex2D( refTex, c+0.5f, f+0.5f);
```

My question is why do we add `0.5f` to both `c` and `f`?
This confuses me..
thankyou

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In graphics, a texture is a set of samples that describes the visual appearance of a surface. A sample is a point. That is, it has no size (as opposed to a pixel that has a physical size). When using samples to determine the colors of pixels, each sample is positioned in the exact center of its corresponding pixel. When addressing pixels with whole number coordinates, the exact center for a given pixel becomes its whole number coordinate plus an offset of 0.5 (in each dimension).

In other words, adding 0.5 to texture coordinates ensures that, when reading from those coordinates, the exact value of the sample for that pixel is returned.

However, it is only when `filterMode` for the texture has been set to `cudaFilterModeLinear` that the value that is read from a texture varies within a pixel. In that mode, reading from coordinates that are not in the exact center of a pixel returns values that are interpolated between the sample for the given pixel and the samples for neighboring pixels. So, adding 0.5 to whole number coordinates effectively negates the `cudaFilterModeLinear` mode. But, since adding 0.5 to the texture coordinates takes up cycles in the kernel, it is better to simply turn off the interpolation by setting `filterMode` to `cudaFilterModePoint`. Then, reading from any coordinate within a pixel returns the exact texture sample value for that pixel, and so, texture samples can be read directly by using whole numbers.

When using `cudaFilterModePoint`, if any floating point math is involved in calculating the texture coordinates, care must be taken to ensure that floating point inaccuracies don't cause the texture coordinates to fall outside the range for the intended target pixel.

Also, as the comments mention, there might be a problem in your code. Adding 0.5f to the texture coordinates implies that the `cudaFilterModeLinear` mode is being used, but that mode returns a float, not an int.

Comment: You said that for textures coordinates are actually point to a pixel center so if we can access element with coordinates 0,0 and use your scheme we get 1,1 pixel.

Comment: @marina.k: I'm not sure what you mean. Is there an issue with the answer?

Comment: @Roger Dahl Thankyou,very nice answer.
But can you elaborate when you say floating point inaccuracies might cause the co ordinates to fall outside the range for the intended target pixel?What do you mean by floating point in accuracies?

Comment: If you use `cudaFilterModePoint` and don't add 0.5, then 3.0 would address pixel #3, but 2.9999999 would address pixel #2. Calculations with floating point values are often not exact, so a calculation that you might expect to come out as the value 3.0 may be a tiny bit higher or lower. In this case, a value that is a tiny bit lower would address a different pixel. If you add 0.5, the addressing is much more tolerant to such small errors.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the texture properties, the value returned by `tex2D` may be linearly interpolated. In that case, the "indices" `f` and `c` should not be integers, but continuous values between the limits of each dimension.

What is a bit odd in this example is that the return value is an integer, which will make any linear interpolant piecewise constant anyway.

For more detailed information, see Section 3.2.10 of the CUDA Programming Guide.

Comment: "`cudaFilterModeLinear` is only valid for returned values of floating-point type.", so here we can't have interpolation, only `cudaFilterModePoint`

Comment: @aland: That is correct, but we don't know what type `refTex` was declared with, i.e. `float` or `int` or whatever.

Comment: If we use coordinates not from 0.0 to 1.0 it can't be `cudaFilterModePoint`

Comment: @marina.k: According to the CUDA Programming Guide, normalized texture coordinates have no influence on the filtering mode. The example in Section 3.2.10.1.3 uses normalized coordinates and linear filtering/interpolation.